# How to get a display for android Calculator with 0 in the beginning?

Tags: java, android, calculator

I am working on an android Calculator application. I am using `TextView` for my Calculator's Display.

My question is "How do i get a display for my Calculator with `0` in the beginning and when pressed any number, `0` should be replaced by that number?". I am using Eclipse to make this app.

This is the String I used for the text in TextView:

```
Name: txtdisplay
Value: 0
```

This is my Code for the TextView:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtDisplay"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:maxLength="20"
    android:text="@string/txtdisplay"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textSize="24.5sp" />
```

This is my Java Code for the TextView:

```
TextView txtDisplay;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    txtDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtDisplay);

}

int clear_flag = 0;

public void shownum(String num) {
    if (clear_flag == 1) {
        txtDisplay.setText("");
        clear_flag = 0;
    }
    else if (txtDisplay.getText() == "0") {
        txtDisplay.setText("");
    }
    txtDisplay.setText(txtDisplay.getText() + num);
}
```

Comment: Don't handle `num` as a String. Instead convert it from the text to numeric for use, and then format it for the `TextView`. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    txtDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtDisplay);
    txtDisplay.setText("0");
}

public void shownum(String num) {
    if (clear_flag == 1) {
        txtDisplay.setText("");
        clear_flag = 0;
    }
    else if (txtDisplay.getText() == "0") {
        txtDisplay.setText("");
    }
    Integer lCurrentValue = Integer.valueOf(txtDisplay.getText().toString());
    Integer lNewValue = Integer.valueOf(num);
    txtDisplay.setText(lCurrentValue+lNewValue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much.

Modifying the Code by changing

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtDisplay"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:maxLength="20"
    android:text="@string/txtdisplay"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textSize="24.5sp" />
```

to

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtDisplay"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:maxLength="20"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textSize="24.5sp" />
```

and adding

```
txtDisplay.setText("0");
```

to

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    txtDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtDisplay);

}
```

and also deleting the unwanted String `txtdisplay` from the `strings.xml` file solved my problem.

So, my new Code for the TextView is:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtDisplay"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:maxLength="20"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textSize="24.5sp" />
```

and my new Java Code for the TextView is:

```
TextView txtDisplay;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    txtDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtDisplay);

    txtDisplay.setText("0");

}

int clear_flag = 0;

public void shownum(String num) {
    if (clear_flag == 1) {
        txtDisplay.setText("");
        clear_flag = 0;
    }
    else if (txtDisplay.getText() == "0") {
        txtDisplay.setText("");
    }
    txtDisplay.setText(txtDisplay.getText() + num);
}
```